# How will write jasmine to cover my function? I am getting error "config method in not exist"

Tags: jasmine

Getting error to my function which I am trying to cover in Jasmine
    `"Error is config method does not exist"` And config the method which I am trying to cover.

I am expecting to cover the right test case scenario to my config method.

```
const config = () => {
    return ({
      name: 'modal.name',
      class: 'modal.class',
      choice: 'modal.choice'
    });
  }

describe('Config', () => {
  it('config is defined', () => {
    let data = {
      name: 'modal.name',
      class: 'modal.class',
      choice: 'modal.choice'
    };
    Object.assign(config, data);
    spyOn(data, 'config').and.returnValue(Promise.resolve(data));
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting that error because you are trying to spy the `config` method in your `data` object with the statement:

```
spyOn(data, 'config').and.returnValue(Promise.resolve(data));
```

The `data` object has no `config` method so, when you call `spyOn` it throws that error.

Your `it` says that you are trying to test that `config` is defined, but you are doing really strange things in your test. If you want to check that `config` is defined you could do:

```
it('config is defined', () => {
    expect(config).toBeDefined();
});
```

A more elaborated test would be to test that the method, besides existing, returns the data you want:

```
it('config returns the configuration', () => {
    expect(config()).toEqual({
        name: 'modal.name',
        class: 'modal.class',
        choice: 'modal.choice'
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, yes that point i realise later :) But after that change, now issue has been resolve. but still still function is not covered. I am geeting message "function is not covered and for return statement is not covered". Can you please suggest me for that.

Comment: I have edited my code to add a test that checks that the method returns the right configuration.